# Flash PDF viewer (with own hosting)

Tags: flash, pdf, converters, viewer

**Looking for a solution similar to the Issuu viewer**. I have a book publishing house and would like to sell access to online publications. Looking for something similar to Issuu but with the possibility of hosting on your server (own domain).

What's important:

**- no ads**
**- no branding**
- I wish that the publication was **in some way protected**
- blocked printing and downloading
- vector text
- i have most of the PDF files, but sometimes they will be ppt files
- something cheap :)

tnx

Comment: Did you look at FlexPaper? http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want self-hosting solution, try **[Pressmo](http://pressmo.com) document to flash converter**.

With Pressmo you can upload PDF, DOC, PPT, wait until conversion finishes and then download flash catalog that can be uploaded on your webserver, and displayed in a fully standalone way.

Some security-connected advantages of Pressmo:

- keeping publication on your own server seems to be more secure, because it can be prevented programmatically to display it from other site than you domain
- avaiable password protection
- text is converted to vectors so it's not trivial to extract content
- saving, printing, original file downloading are optionable (can be turned off/on or disabled)
- available water marks protection

Here is the [example](http://pressmo.com/pdf-flash-example/1).

Answer (score 1):

An open-source tool for converting pdf to swf is http://www.swftools.org/

On your server convert the pdf to swf and then send the swf to your viewer.

The FlexPaper tool yms mentioned is basically a really good viewer on top of pdf2swf.